# Please help me identify the Lego set

Tags: set-identification

This partial build was put together symmetrically. Both sides are moveable.

[image: this thingy]

Comment: Hi nnLego! When uploading pictures please do not remove the text saying "enter description here" because without it the image will not render and we won't see it, and we'll end up thinking that you  **didn't** add a picture and we would close your question. Thank goodness I checked!

Comment: Actually, best way is to really insert descriptions there ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the rear part of [70009-1: Worriz's Combat Lair](https://brickset.com/sets/70009-1/Worriz-s-Combat-Lair):

[image]

Comment: Oh, we managed to answer simultaneously. Upvoted!

Comment: Aw shucks, now all because of my misleading answer I deceived the OP and he's no longer active now apparently and won't see *your* correct answer, **all because of me.** Here, I'll give you an upvote, you certainly deserve it.‮‮ ‮ ⁭

Comment: @mindstormsboi Don't be hard on yourself, many new members engage in ask-and-disappear behaviour, and it's been less than a day since OP has asked the question in the first place.

Comment: I think that what the OP has done is unfair, both answers are correct but the OP just accepted only one of the two and gave an extra upvote, which means that you get 35 more rep than Alex (and you probably don't care much about rep at this point) and... I think the OP simply did not even notice the other answer. Should something be done about this?

Comment: @mindstormsboi You're right in that I don't care about rep, but on the other hand I don't really see what is the "something" that could be done about it. I could certainly delete my answer, but that would certainly bring more harm (as it is the accepted answer). I'd gladly upvote Alex's answer for a second time, if I could, so I'm open for any suggestions.

Answer (score 16):

That's part of [Worriz's Combat Lair (70009)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70009-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) set. You can see the cage between second and last axles.

[image]

Comment: Wow, answered in the same second :) Jinx! :D